# Database control model for Android Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a model that plays an intermediate role between the database and my frontend in the android application.

Why do I want to do this?
suppose now I am using directly firebase database but in the future, if I want to change the database then I will have to change all the functionality where the database connection is implemented. So I want to make a generalized model so I will change in model and work will become easy to change the database platform for me and my project team also.

How I can do this and by which model?

Note: I used a NoSQL database(Firebase) now and future changed database will be also NoSQL database(like mongoDB).

Comment: It depends on what database your gonna use if your gonna use sql database then it will be complicated cause firebase is no sql database. So just provide enough information. So other developer can help you.

Comment: You can introduce domain models. So domain models will be according to your front end. and you can map the network model to the domain model. In this way, your front end will be independent. Incase of change, you just need to update the mapping.